# Monero cli show_transfers transactions for only a specific subaddress

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, transaction-data, sub-address, show-transfers

I have a few subaddresses with small amount transactions. How do I view only these transactions that were sent to this subaddress? I already switched to the account **account switch 1**, but when I do show_transfers it shows everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I view only these transactions that were sent to this subaddress?

```
[wallet]: help incoming_transfers 
Command usage: 
  incoming_transfers [available|unavailable] [verbose] [uses] [index=<N1>[,<N2>[,...]]]

Command description: 
  Show the incoming transfers, all or filtered by availability and address index.

  Output format:
  Amount, Spent("T"|"F"), "frozen"|"locked"|"unlocked", RingCT, Global Index, Transaction Hash, Address Index, [Public Key, Key Image]
```

Example:

```
incoming_transfers index=1
```

Shows all incoming transfers to subaddress index 1.